# Html.fromHtml throwing null pointer in editor mode, due to which view cannot render in Android Studio

Tags: android, textview

Since I have upgraded to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 I am facing an issue: my custom view is not compiling in Editor to view the layout. I tried to debug and found out that the Html.fromHtml is throwing NullPointerException when in Editor Mode. When the same layout which is unable to render in editor mode is run on the simulator works fine.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue, or any workaround?

[image: Code]

[image: Android layout view in editor]

Note: It was working fine in previous Android Studio Builds

Answer (score 1):

That seems like the same as is reported in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/262773698. Since that issue is filed against the Compose preview support, you might want to comment there and provide a reproducible project demonstrating that the issue is more general.

You could use [`isInEditMode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View?hl=en#isineditmode) to avoid doing the HTML conversion when in the editor. Or, stick with your `try`/`catch`.